# Use custom pagination or ngx-pagination in ngx-datatable

Tags: angular, web, pagination

I have a datatable in angular and i want to make a custom pagination who can jump to the last page like what shown in the picture.

[image]

Here is what my footer looks like

```
<ngx-datatable-footer>
     <ng-template ngx-datatable-footer-template 
        let-curPage="curPage" 
        let-offset="offset" 
        let-pageSize="pageSize" 
        let-rowCount="rowCount" 
        let-selectedCount="selectedCount">
           <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
              <pagination-controls 
                  itemsPerPage="pageSize"
                  currentPage="curPage"
                  totalItems="rowCount"
                  directionLinks="true"
                  previousLabel="" 
                  nextLabel="" 
                    (pageChange)="onPage($event)">
              </pagination-controls>
           </div>
         </ng-template>
     </ngx-datatable-footer>
```

But it turned out like this only.
[image]

What did I do wrong? Or is there another way to make pagination like what shown in the picture? Thanks

my reference [here](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination)

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination#paginatepipe), you to need place `PaginatePipe`  behind the iterable.

> The PaginatePipe should be placed at the end of an NgFor expression.
> It accepts a single argument, an object conforming to the
> PaginationInstance interface.

Meanwhile, you cannot pass values from `<ngx-datatable-footer-template>` element to `<pagination-control>` element as **`<pagination-control>` does not have `itemsPerPage`, `currentPage` and `totalItems` Input properties**.

---

### Solution

Your `<ngx-datatable>` with `<pagination-control>` elements should be as below:

> .component.html

```
<ngx-datatable 
    [rows]="rows | paginate: { itemsPerPage: pageSize, currentPage: currentPage, totalItems: rows && rows.length }" 
    ...>

    <ngx-datatable-footer>
      <ng-template ngx-datatable-footer-template>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <pagination-controls 
              [directionLinks]="true" 
              previousLabel="" 
              nextLabel="" 
              (pageChange)="currentPage = $event">
          </pagination-controls>
        </div>
        
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-footer>
</ngx-datatable>
```

> .component.ts

```js
currentPage = 1;
pageSize = 10;
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jcfdrm)

---

### References

1. [ngx-pagination](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination#paginatepipe)
2. [PaginationControlComponent](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination/blob/master/src/pagination-controls.component.ts)
3. [PaginatePipe](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination/blob/master/src/paginate.pipe.ts)